# Utilizando un for en R para generar una tabla de lanzamientos de moneda

Tags: r, loops

Revisando los ejercicios para loops de este sitio

https://www.r-bloggers.com/loops-in-r-exercises/

Me causó curiosidad el número 5: 
"Usar un for loop para simular 20 lanzamientos de una moneda 20 veces, registrando los resultados (1 = heads, 0 = tails) en un vector preestablecido" (traducción propia)

La solución que propone el autor es esta

```
n <- 20
coin_outc <- vector(length = n, mode = "integer")
for (i in 1:20) {
  coin_outc[i] <- sample(c(0L, 1L), 1)
}
coin_outc

##  [1] 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Aunque yo pude obtener un acercamiento similar con

```
for (i in 1:20) {
x[i] <- sample(c(0,1), 1)
}
table(x)

x
 0  1 
11  9 

##Ojo: El número de 0 y 1 varía por cada llamada al loop.
```

Que además genera la tabla de frecuencias.

Ahora bien, quiero ir un poco más allá para que, en lugar de solo reportar la frecuencia de 0 y 1, la table indique el número de heads y de tails, pero con los nombres, es decir algo como:

```
x
 tails  heads 
  11      9
```

He intentado cosas como

```
for (i in 1:20) {
x[i] <- sample(c(0,1), 1)
}
if (x[i] == 0) {
i <- "head"
} else {
i <- "tail"
}
table(x)
```

O esto

```
for (i in 1:20) {
x[i] <- sample(c(0,1), 1)
}
for (i in x) {
if (i==0) {
print("heads")
} else {
print("tails")
}
}
table(x)
```

Que da como resultado (omití algunos renglones)

```
[1] "heads"
[1] "tails"
[1] "tails"
[1] "tails"
[1] "heads"
[1] "tails"
[1] "heads"
[1] "heads"
> table(x)
x
 0  1 
14  6
```

¿Alguna sugerencia de cómo lograr el resultado deseado? Mi interés es que pueda hacerse desde un for, no utilizando algún otro método.
Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que has intentado es correcto, pero pareciera que el `if` lo tuvieras fuera del ciclo. Incluso para hacer más compacto el código podrías usar la función `ifelse()`

```
x <- c()
for (i in 1:20) {
    x[i] <- ifelse(sample(c(0,1), 1)==0, "head", "tail")
}
table(x)

x
head tail 
  12    8
```

Esto si quieres verificar el valor en cada iteración, sino, mucho más óptimo sería, y gracias a que `ifelse()` es una función vectorizada, hacer esto:

```
x <- c()
for (i in 1:20) {
    x[i] <- sample(c(0,1), 1)
}
x <- ifelse(x, "head", "tail")
table(x)
```

Nota, que tampoco es necesario realmente preguntar `sample(c(0,1), 1)==0` ya que por el coercionado automático de R, el 0 será "False" y el 1 "True".

También podría ser útil usar un `Factor` a  partir del vector numérico:

```
x <- c()
for (i in 1:20) {
    x[i] <- sample(c(0,1), 1)
}
x <- factor(x, labels=c("head", "tail"))
table(x)
```

Y por último, no estas obligado a que `sample` retorne un `1` o un `0`, bien podrías hacer esto:

```
x <- c()
for (i in 1:20) {
    x[i] <- sample(c("head","tail"), 1)
}
table(x)
```

**Nota**: Inicializo siempre `x` mediante `x <- c()` simplemente para no tener problemas entre prueba y prueba, el autor hace algo parecido mediante `coin_outc <- vector(length = n, mode = "integer")` solo que ya lo crea con el tamaño y la clase apropiada.

Comment: Buenísima la primera solución utilizando ifelse. ¡Gracias!